about an estimate concerning the Mobius function
I am studying about the zero density estimates of Dirichlet $L$-series, and in a related paper by O. Ramare, he proves the following explicit estimate: for $X \geq 10^{9}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{X < n<5X} \frac{\Big(\sum_{\substack{d\vert n \\ d\leq X}} \mu(d)\Big)^2}{n^2} \leq \frac{0.605}{X}.
\end{equation}
I have a couple of questions about the proof. First of all, it computes separately the contributions coming from $n \in (X, 2X]$ and from $n \in (2X, 5X)$. I do not see the reasoning behind this?.....
Secondly, when $n \in (X, 2X]$, it says that in that case the coefficient $\sum_{\substack{d\vert n \\ d\leq X}} \mu(d)$ is equal to $-\mu(n)$. I do not seem to understand why this is true??
And also, thirdly, the other case, when $n \in (2X, 5X)$, the coefficient $\sum_{\substack{d\vert n \\ d\leq X}} \mu(d)$ takes values in $\{-1, 0, 1\}$; the only non-trivial cases being when $n$ is divisible by 2 and 3, where the coefficient has value $-\mu(n) - \mu(n/2) - \mu(n/3)$. Why?
I was playing around with some values of $n$ and $X$ to get an insight and it seemed true to me, but I do not seem to get it for the general case. Once we have these values for the coefficients, the rest of the proof is pretty straightforward; use of partial summation formula and a previously known bound for $\sum_{n\leq X} \mu^{2}(n)$, but the above three things I am stuck with.
Any help or pointers would be highly helpful since I really need to understand this...

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

do you know the fundamental identity $\sum_{d |n}\mu(d)=0$ for $n>1$? if you do then the claims are trivial (hint when $n \in (X, 2X]$ all the divisors $d$ of $n$ are at most $X$ except $n$ itself so the sum in question becomes  $\sum_{d |n, d \ne n}\mu(d)=-\mu(n)$ by the above; in the other case $n \in (2X,5X)$ it's the same though $n/2$ or $n/3$ can be divisors that are greater than $X$ (and $n/4$ but that is an easy case to deal with) etc

Aha, I see that now right away, thanks. And, I believe your comment also addresses the rationale behind the split up of the intervals. Thanks, I am aware of that identity....I was thinking if it had to do with the lower bound on X....
